# inner join with avg sql query

Tags: sql

I am new to sql, I am working with salary table that has id and amount rows (by years - every employee can have up to 30 rows of salary) and employee table that has id name and last name rows, I would like to get the average salary of every emplyee and first and last name, I am not sure why it is not working for me:

```
SELECT t.FIRST_NAME, AVG(g.SALARY)
  FROM SALARIES AS g
  JOIN EMPLOYEES as t
    ON t.EMP_NO = g.EMP_NO
 GROUP BY t.EMP_NO;
```

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to select the columns you want.

Second, you need for the `SELECT` columns to be consistent with the `GROUP BY` columns.

So, I would suggest:

```
SELECT e.EMP_NO, e.LAST_NAME, e.FIRST_NAME, AVG(s.SALARY)
FROM SALARIES s JOIN
     EMPLOYEES e
     ON e.EMP_NO = s.EMP_NO
GROUP BY e.EMP_NO, e.LAST_NAME, e.FIRST_NAME;
```

This takes the average of all rows in `salaries` that match a row in `employees`.  If `salaries` has multiple rows for an employee -- storing changes over time for instance -- then the average may not be what you want to calculate.